# Query an element of an array and the ones before in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is an example of my data.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fa7d0e31abef4382b15efd0"),
        "users" : {
                "5fa667194f22083924eeca9e" : {
                        "toRead" : 0
                },
                "5fac51148566866156d09d36" : {
                        "toRead" : 1
                }
        },
        "messages" : [
                {
            "messageId": ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca5e"),
                        "userId" : ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca9e"),
                        "message" : "Hello"
                },
                {
            "messageId": ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca6e"),
                        "userId" : ObjectId("5fac51148566866156d09d36"),
                        "message" : "Hi"
                },
                {
            "messageId": ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca7e"),
                        "userId" : ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca9e"),
                        "message" : "How are you ?"
                },
                {
            "messageId": ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca8e"),
                        "userId" : ObjectId("5fac51148566866156d09d36"),
                        "message" : "Fine and you ?"
                },
                {
            "messageId": ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca9f"),
                        "userId" : ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca9e"),
                        "message" : "Fine thanks !"
                },
        ]
}
```

I would like to find the element of the array and two element before the one I found.

For example, if I'm looking for a message where :

messageId = ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca8e")

The result should be an array "messages" containing a message where :

```
messageId = ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca8e")
```

And two message before this one. In this example it would be :

```
messageId = ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca7e") 
messageId = ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca6e")
```

So the result would be :

```
        "messages" : [
                {
            "messageId": ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca6e"),
                        "userId" : ObjectId("5fac51148566866156d09d36"),
                        "message" : "Hi"
                },
                {
            "messageId": ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca7e"),
                        "userId" : ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca9e"),
                        "message" : "How are you ?"
                },
                {
            "messageId": ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca8e"),
                        "userId" : ObjectId("5fac51148566866156d09d36"),
                        "message" : "Fine and you ?"
                }
        ]
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `messages` array
- `$match` is `messageId` is less than or equal to your input `messageId`
- `$sort` by `messageId` in descending order
- `$limit` 3 documents
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `messages` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$messages" },
  {
    $match: {
      "messages.messageId": {
        $lte: ObjectId("5fa667194f22083924eeca8e")
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "messages.messageId": -1 } },
  { $limit: 3 },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      users: { $first: "$users" },
      messages: { $push: "$messages" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DvolhBXn9AN)

Comment: Thanks for the playground. I'm concerned with the "$lte" statement. What if ObjectId are not in ascending order ? Because there's only 4 bytes for the timestamp in seconds and then it's a random value. So it could be possible that if two messages are sent at the same time, the upper one in the array have a higher ObjectId value than the second one.

Comment: it could be but, when $unwind it will maintain order same as it is that was in messages array, i don't think this query will change order look at the same timestamp messageid 
 in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YoYTdFr5GOE), but main concern how it will insert when message receive in same time.

Comment: Take a look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ahLR3ekCBgx). I'd like the query to return the three message before the one I searched, no matter what are the messageId of the messages before. For example, in this playground, it returns the three messages after the one i'm looking for, the opposite.

Comment: It is happening because all 5 messages having same timestamp, how it will identify the previous 2? 
in this situation there are no possibility to identify who is first and who is second, if you know then share. 
it is rare of the rare case 2 messages are inserted in same time, because comparison is on millisecond, 
you should have to maintain some rules on insert, 
1) new message push always goes at the end of the array, so $unwind always maintain order of element from array

Comment: I will not recommend this way [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cIGVC-ckmMn), because it will select previous 2 messages without looking at timestamp. i can say this is prediction.

Comment: The timestamp on the ObjectId is precise to the second, no to the millisecond according to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/
Thank you very much for your help ! I finally have a solution for my problem thanks to you !